# How to know whether Kafka was upgraded?

Tags: apache-kafka

I was trying to upgrade Kafka from 0.8.2.1 to 0.10.2. I followed the following steps:

1.Updated server.properties file on broker and add the following properties:

```
 inter.broker.protocol.version=0.8.2
  log.message.format.version=0.8.2
```

2.Upgrade the brokers one at a time: shut down the broker and restart it.

3.Once the entire cluster is upgraded, bumped the protocol version by editing inter.broker.protocol.version and setting it to 0.10.2.

4.Restarted the brokers one by one for the new protocol version to take effect.

But, I don't think Kafka was upgraded. Is there any way to check the whether Kafka was upgraded successfully or not. Am I missing something in the above steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you could check all jar files under kafka/libs to see it they are versioned 0.10.2.

Secondly, start the broker servers, check server.log and search `INFO Kafka version : 0.10.2.0`

Thirdly, prompt a terminal and try to execute the script below (You definitely got failed to upgrade if there is no such script):

```
bin/kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

And the output should display that current max version for OffsetFetch request is 2 which proves a upgrade success, as shown below:

> OffsetFetch(9): 0 to **2** [usable: 2]

Comment: kafka/libs folder still contains jars versioned 0.8.2.1 and kafka-broker-api-versions.sh is not available inside bin. I followed the steps as per the documentation (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_10_2_0), but was unable to upgrade. Any idea what I missed ?

Comment: No, i did not do that. Can you tell me what do I need to do for updating code binary. I am a bit new to kafka :D

Comment: You should replace the old binary files with the new ones. Alternatively, just use the new binaries at all but with the original `server.properties`

Comment: I got your point. But I don't have any clarification regarding time interval between the two restarts, I mean, once I restart the broker after updating the binaries, then how long do I need to wait before stopping it and changing to latest version in server.properties. Thanks in advance !!